# Printing the right list items in Python from an SQL database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Python reading my textfile with keywords for each line and then I let SQL select it and fetch it in Python, but I don't know the right list comprehension or code to exclude the keywords which couldn't be read by SQL. It only prints the last word from the loop and I want both keywords to be included.

So I have these keywords in a random textfile:

```
Bohemian Rhapsody

You're

Thriller

Just some random words
```

The database found tracks for the first two but didn't for the 3rd and 4th line in the file . I want a print statement which says: --- No tracks found for Thriller, Just some random words ---

My code:

import sqlite3, sys

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\Just\Downloads\chinook.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
import_file = input ('Enter file name: ')
with open(import_file, 'r') as f:                        
    unfiltered = f.read().splitlines()
    keywords = [filter_empty for filter_empty in unfiltered if filter_empty]

for keyword in keywords:
        
    cur.execute('''SELECT tracks.TrackId, tracks.Name, artists.Name
                FROM tracks
                INNER JOIN albums ON tracks.AlbumId = albums.AlbumId
                INNER JOIN artists ON albums.ArtistId = artists.ArtistId
                WHERE tracks.name LIKE (?||'%') ''',(keyword,))
    found_tracks = cur.fetchall()
    unknown_tracks = []

    if len(found_tracks) == 0:
        print (keyword)
        unknown_tracks += [keyword]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  keyword is not found in the database, the result of this `cur.fetchall()` will be an empty list. Add a test for that condition and output the desired message.

Comment: The problem is I also need to skip empty lines in the file, like I did with the code:
trefwoorden = [filter_lege_lines for filter_lege_lines in ongefilterd if filter_lege_lines]
and it also skips the empty list from cur.fetchall(). I don't know how to apply both this filter and your suggestion.

Comment: I edited my question and I found a condition for it but now it only prints the last keyword and i want all keywords for the condition

Comment: if `print(keyword)` is _outside_ the if loop, it will print every `keyword`. Currently only prints "not found" keyword.  Beware, `unknown_tracks` is initialized to empty list _for each keyword_. Perhaps i'm not understanding; an example of desired output might clear things up.

Comment: unknown_tracks was indeed initialized in the for loop and I moved i out the for loop and now i got both items. Thank you!